# How to find port number by Process ID(PID) on macOS？

Tags: macos, port

I know on Linux, we can use **netstat** to display all connections which include port, and then use **grep** to find which port is used by the specified PID. For example, we can use this command to find which port is used by PID 1234:

```
netstat -antpe | grep 1234
```

However, I don't know how to do this on macOS, I want to know how to find which port is used by the specified PID. I think there is some command can do this. Does anyone know how to do that? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try searching for the solution before asking the question. This is a fairly common question.

Comment: @AbhaySrivastav I have searched this problem, but don't get some useful answers.

Comment: Now, I know we can use "lsof -i | grep PID" to solve this problem.